# adding string together in jQuery option argument

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am writing an autocomplete form with multiple types of data.

In the HTML, data types are separated by using the key attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="data0" value="" size="20" id="data0" key="country"/>
<input type="text" name="data1" value="" size="20" id="data1" key="state"/>
```

In the js file, I run a wildcard selector on input and use the autocomplete this way:

```
$(function() {
$(":input").autocomplete({
    source: "query.php?type="+$(this).attr("key")+"&mode=1",
    minLength: 2
});
});
```

But it does not work.

I wondered if it is due to the .attr() selector, so I wrote another code to test it:

```
var test="state";
$(function() {
$(":input").autocomplete({
    source: "query.php?type="+test+"&mode=1",
    minLength: 2
});
});
```

does not work either.

Thank you in advance for the help!

edit:

```
$(function() {
$(":input").autocomplete({
    source: "query.php?type=state&mode=1",
    minLength: 2
});
});
```

this will work. So I am sure it is not a selector problem.

Comment: Which autocomplete plugin are you using?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc the one supplied in jqueryui and modded to work with POST. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-autocomplete-new-parameter-implemented-method-get-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
$(":input").autocomplete({
    source: "query.php?type="+$(this).attr("key")+"&mode=1",
    minLength: 2
});
});
```

Will not work because `this` doesn't point to what you think it does. You could do something like this...

```
$(":input").each(function() {
   $(this).autocomplete({
    source: "query.php?type="+encodeURIComponent($(this).attr("key"))+"&mode=1",
    minLength: 2
   });
});
```

You also ought to encode the parameter above, as I have done for you.

Comment: I have already tested my code replacing "query.php?type="+$(this).attr("key")+"&mode=1" with "query.php?type=state&mode=1" and it works. so i think it is a question of appending strings together in the argument and not the selector. thanks though.

Comment: @shiroin My code is different - the `this` will resolve to each individual `input` because it is encapsulated in jQuery's set `each()`.